# Simple DataTable initialization with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm just having some trouble initializing a DataTable using Ajax and PHP. According to the inspector the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.dataTables.js:2649
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.js:2649
oSettings.jqXHR.$.ajax.success jquery.dataTables.js:8749
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
k jquery.js:8235
r jquery.js:8778
```

I've followed the instructions as on datatable website but apparently I'm doing something wrong. It's not the php part, I've just checked it and it is returning a json file.

Here's what I've got.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chromo Insiders</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript" src="insiders.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ci_style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    @import 'DataTables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css';
</style>
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <h1>Chromo Insiders</h1>
</header>

<table id="datatables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Date Registered</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


$('#datatables').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'process.php'
    } );

});
```

Just in case you need to take a look to the php code:

```
<?php

        try {
            $conn = require_once 'dbConnect.php';

            $sql = "SELECT email, lastName, firstName, state, dateRegistered FROM Users";

            $result = $conn->prepare($sql) or die ($sql);

            if(!$result->execute()) return false;

            if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                $json = array();
                while($row = $result->fetch()){
                    $json[] = array(
                        'email' => $row['email'],
                        'lastName' => $row['lastName'],
                        'firstName' => $row['firstName'],
                        'dateRegistered' => $row['dateRegistered'],
                        'state' => $row['state']
                    );
                }

                $json['success'] = true;
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

Comment: are you sure it's not returning false?

Comment: @FrankConry from the browser I called the php file and it showed me the json document, not sure but I think that says that it's returning true, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your response as such:

```
        if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
            $json = array();
            while($row = $result->fetch()){
                /**  MAKE ARRAY NON ASSOCIATIVE **/
                $json[] = array(
                    $row['email'],
                    $row['lastName'],
                    $row['firstName'],
                    $row['dateRegistered'],
                    $row['state']
                );
            }
            /*** MAKE RESPONSE HAVE 'aaData' ENTRY ****/
            $response = array();
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['aaData'] = $json;
            echo json_encode($response);
```

Reference here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html. Specifically:

> DataTables expects an object with an array called "aaData" with the
>   data source.

Also your table does not have a 'state' column, although your ajax response does...

Comment: I made the changes as you said and it showed me: DataTables warning (table id='datatables'): Resquested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0. The weird part is that the table says that it has 58 records, meaning that it's being populated but the records are not there. Also, what you mean with 'state' column? What is that for? Thanks

Comment: ah, probably dont make it an associative array. Like this: `$json[] = array($row['email'],
      $row['lastName'],
      $row['firstName'],
      $row['dateRegistered'],
      $row['state']
                );`