# Is it possible to pass in an array of objects into DataTables?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

After PHP passes back the results of a SQL query in this format:

```
[0]: Object
    name: "Bruce Wayne"
    occupation: "Billionaire Playboy" 


[1]: Object
    name: "Tony Stark"
    occupation: "Billionaire Playboy"
```

Can you pass it into DataTables, or does it needed to be in a .json file?

Comment: Found the solution by modifying code given on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764782/simple-datatable-initialization-with-ajax-and-php)